# Flutter Flow - Use actions provided by Parent component in Child Component

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutterflow

I am using Flutter flow to build an app that has a **List view** of **buttons** which when clicked changes the background of the list view. So, for example, my list has 2 items Nature and Space, when Nature is clicked it should **change the background** of the **List view (NOT button)** to nature's image and similarly for space.

How I am trying to achieve this:

I have made an item as a reusable component that takes an action as a parameter.

Example:

[image: Image of the section showing a list of parameters for the child component]

In the parent list view, one state variable is being used to define the background image, and as the definition of the child's action parameter (in this example: updateMenuImage), this variable is updated based on the action's parameter.

[image: Image of the section showing how parameter is defined in parent]

Now, the problem is in the **Action Editor of the child widget**, I am **not getting any option** to select this action (which is passed as a component parameter to it).

I would like to know, how we can achieve this or if it is not possible with the current release.

[image: How it is being used in Button of List View]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an [Execute Callback](https://docs.flutterflow.io/actions/actions/utilities/execute-callback) action.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).